# not valid at this position, expecting an identifier. error occurs

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NM    ( IN   PARAM_A          VARCHAR(16)       
                                 , IN   PARAM_B          VARCHAR(16) ) 

BEGIN
    DECLARE SRCH_CNTE VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT IN PARAM_A + PARAM_B;
    DECLARE SQL_NM    VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT 'PROCEDURE_NM';
    DECLARE ERROR_YN  VARCHAR(1)   DEFAULT 'N';
    DECLARE ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL;
    BEGIN
        CALL PROC_LOG(SRCH_CNTE, SQL_NM, ERROR_YN, ERROR_MSG);
    END;
    
    BEGIN
        --SOMETHING
    END;
    
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
                    ERROR_MSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                    ERROR_YN  = 'Y';  
                    CALL PROC_LOG(SRCH_CNTE, SQL_NM, ERROR_YN, ERROR_MSG);
            END;
    END;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

"ERROR_YN" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier.
syntax error occurs.

I have completed the variable declaration, and I don't think there's anything missing.
What should I fix?

Comment: Assignment statements require the `SET` keyword: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Comment: after change,    SET @param = value;
 still error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 someVarient=RETURNED_SQLSTATE
              , ERROR_MSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                
                CALL PROC_LOG(SRCH_CNTE, SQL_NM, 'Y', ERROR_MSG);
        END;
END;
```

It was successfully committed after changing to the code above.